# Blocking all ports but a few in iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

I am attempting to `DROP` all ports but one in iptables.

After running the following commands:

```
iptables -N WHITELIST
iptables -A INPUT --jump WHITELIST
iptables -A WHITELIST --protocol tcp --match tcp --dport 4444 --jump DROP
iptables -A WHITELIST --jump ACCEPT
```

I can spin up a netcat listener on both port 4444 and another arbitrary port, and can confirm that I cannot connect to port 4444 but can connect to the other port.

However, trying to flip these commands on it's head like so:

```
iptables -N WHITELIST
iptables -A INPUT -j WHITELIST
iptables -A WHITELIST --protocol tcp --match tcp --dport 4444 --jump ACCEPT
iptables -A WHITELIST --jump DROP
```

No inbound connections are accepted, even on port 4444. I can confirm that the instructions are in the correct order, as seen above, and I flush and delete each chain and relevant instruction between each test.

How can I block every port except for a few in iptables? TIA.

Edit:

When running tests when doing nobody's suggestion, I ended up logs like these in `dmesg`:

```
[ 1962.379494] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=4444 DPT=57378 WINDOW=65483 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
[ 1962.379503] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=4444 DPT=57378 WINDOW=65483 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
```

Another interesting thing is that this appears to block outbound traffic as well, making me unable to access websites from firefox.

Comment: Add `iptables -A WHITELIST -j LOG` before and after ACCEPT line to see what happens there. Check for log entries and see what is written there.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! I added more information to my question.

Comment: We don't know what service is running there. From the log it seems, that also connections on loopback interface are blocked. Try to only work on the network interface, as the results are a bit unpredictible as it is.

Comment: Thank you so much @stoney! Specifying a network interface solves both of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Simply specifying a network interface like this:

```
iptables -N WHITELIST
iptables -A INPUT -j WHITELIST
iptables -i wlan0 -A WHITELIST --protocol tcp --match tcp --dport 4444 --jump ACCEPT
iptables -i wlan0 -A WHITELIST --jump DROP
```

solves both inbound connection problems as well as allowing outbound connections.

Comment: I believe this will also block inbound traffic for already established connections. Typically you'd also want to allow traffic that matches these connections using conntrack, like `-i wlan0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`